# Estrutura de repetição para inserir dados em um form group

Tags: angular

Tenho o seguinte form group:

```
 this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

    variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

 });

  createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      valor: '',
      preco: null,
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
      id: '',
      id_produto: '',
      created_at: ''
    });
  }
```

Meu template:

```
<form *ngIf="mostraVariacoes" [formGroup]="variacaoForm">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
          <div class="container-fluid" [formGroup]="item">
```

Em um momento da minha aplicação eu recebo do backend os dados e preciso inseri-los nesse form group que eu criei.

Tentei algo como:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.produto.variacao.length;i++){
  (<FormControl>this.variacaoForm.value['variacoes'])
  .setValue(this.produto.variacao[i], { onlySelf: true });
}
```

Porém recebo:

> this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.setValue is not a function

Também tentei:

for(let i=0;ithis.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes'])
  .setValue(this.produto.variacao[i], { onlySelf: true });
}

Assim eu recebo:

> ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control at index: 0.

Comment: tente [esse código](https://codeshare.io/5MXZx3) se der certo eu coloco como resposta

Comment: Não deu certo, acredito que eu devo adicionar chamando minha função:

    this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup(produto)])

    });

mas ainda assim não deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.produto.variacao.length;i++){
  this.variacoes.push(this.createFormGroup(produto,i));
}

  createFormGroup(produto?: any, indice?: number): FormGroup {
    if(produto){
      return this.fb.group({
        valor: produto.variacao[indice].valor,
        preco: produto.variacao[indice].preco,
        sku: produto.variacao[indice].sku,
        tipo: produto.variacao[indice].tipo,
        id: '',
        id_produto: '',
        created_at: ''
      });
    }else{
    return this.fb.group({
      valor: '',
      preco: null,
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
      id: '',
      id_produto: '',
      created_at: ''
    });
  }
}
```